# Matching hour-minute-second (hms) duration string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match the digits before `h`, `m`, and `s` into their respective capture groups. I want to match all 3 groups if possible. If one or two of the other groups are missing then match the last group(s).

As seen in the image below and in this [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kFA0KT/1), I have currently a regex of
`/(\d+)(?=h)|(\d+)(?=m)|(\d+)(?=s)/g`, which matches, for my test string, 12 matches with 1 group in each match.

[image: regex and string]

But `I want` 7 matches. Where the first match contains 3 groups, the 2:nd to 4:th match contain 2 groups each and the last 3 matches contain 1 group each.

So `I want:`

1. Match 1: `11h22m33s`

   1. Group 1: `11`
   2. Group 2: `22`
   3. Group 3: `33`
2. Match 2: `11h22m`

   1. Group 1: `11`
   2. Group 2: `22`
3. Match 3: `11h33s`

   1. Group 1: `11`
   2. Group 2: `33`
4. Match 4: `22m33s`

   1. Group 1: `22`
   2. Group 2: `33`
5. Match 5: `11h`

   1. Group 1: `11`
6. Match 6: `22m`

   1. Group 1: `22`
7. Match 7: `33s`

   1. Group 1: `33`

### Edit

The test strings can be contained within other strings! E.g. `08:00 + 11h`. See https://regex101.com/r/RWA9Oy/1

Comment: Maybe `^(?!$)(?:(\d+)h)?(?:(\d+)m)?(?:(\d+)s)?$`? See https://regex101.com/r/dLe77O/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah, that did the trick! Do you mind me asking if you could explain it a little? Because I tried earlier using non-capturing groups with the ?-quantifier and it didn't work for me. I see you did that but also used negative lookahead with end of line - not quite sure why though.

Also if you post an answer I'll accept it! :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I just realized your regex doesn't work if the expression is contained within another string. I'll update the question. Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to make sure the whole string matches the pattern, you can use

```
^(?!$)(?:(\d+)h)?(?:(\d+)m)?(?:(\d+)s)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dLe77O/1).

If you need to extract these strings from the longer texts, you can use

```
\b(?=\w)(?:(\d+)h)?(?:(\d+)m)?(?:(\d+)s)?\b(?!\w)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dLe77O/3).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!$)` - the string can't end at the very start (=cannot be empty)
- `\b(?=\w)` - a word boundary where the char immediately on the right is a word char (=is a letter, digit or `_`)
- `(?:(\d+)h)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching one or more digits (capturing them into Group 1) and a `h` letter
- `(?:(\d+)m)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching one or more digits (capturing them into Group 2) and a `m` letter
- `(?:(\d+)s)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching one or more digits (capturing them into Group 3) and a `s` letter
- `$` - end of string
- `\b(?!\w)` - a word boundary where the char immediately on the right is NOT a word char or at the end of string.

Just in case you want allow any amount of whitespace between the components, you may add `\s*`:

```
^(?!\s*$)\s*(?:(\d+)\s*h\s*)?(?:(\d+)\s*m\s*)?(?:(\d+)\s*s)?\s*$
```

Or, for partial matching

```
\b(?=\w)(?:(\d+)\s*h\s*)?(?:(\d+)\s*m\s*)?(?:(\d+)\s*s)?\b(?!\w)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dLe77O/2) and [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dLe77O/4).